# Correct syntaxt for multiple 301 redirects in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect several pages from old URLs to new ones.

```
Redirect 301 /eng/loc.php /en/location/
Redirect 301 /eng/rest.php /en/restaurant
Redirect 301 /eng/accom.php /en/accommodation-rates
Redirect 301 /eng/fish.php /en/fishing
Redirect 301 /eng/hiking.php /en/hiking-cycling
```

This works until I add this line:

```
Redirect 301 /eng /en/home
```

Adding this causes the URLs in the first code block to be output wrongly. I assume it is a conflict down to my bad syntax but cannot find a similar solution in stackoverflow and cannot apply my problem to the documentation for htaccess files.

I have tried adding escape \ and also \s to the "/eng" in the above line but that was not the issue.

What would the correct syntax be here?

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution was use `RedirectMatch` for the "directory". The original 'solution' of quotation marks for each url was wrong as I found out later when redirecting other links.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/eng$  /en/home  
Redirect 301 "/eng/loc.php" "/en/location/"
Redirect 301 "/eng/rest.php" "/en/restaurant"
Redirect 301 "/eng/accom.php" "/en/accommodation-rates"
Redirect 301 "/eng/fish.php" "/en/fishing"
Redirect 301 "/eng/hiking.php" "/en/hiking-cycling"
```

This is where I found the solution: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch/